# Sum values of PairRDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD of type:

```
dataset :org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Double)] = MapPartitionRDD[26]
```

Which is equivalent to `(Pedro, 0.0833), (Hello, 0.001828) ...`

I'd like to sum all the value , `0.0833+0.001828..` but I can't find a proper
solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering your input data, you can do the following :

```
// example
val datasets = sc.parallelize(List(("Pedro", 0.0833), ("Hello", 0.001828))) 
datasets.map(_._2).sum()
// res3: Double = 0.085128
// or
datasets.map(_._2).reduce(_ + _)
// res4: Double = 0.085128
// or even
datasets.values.sum()
// res5: Double = 0.085128
```

Comment: How about values instead of _._2?

Answer (score 2):

like this?:

```
map(_._2).reduce((x, y) => x + y)
```

breakdown: map the tuple to just the double values, then reduce the RDD by summing.